# How do you use "was" to connect to sentences?

Tags: english-to-german

I wish to say in German:

**I don't know, what must I write about!**

I thought about 2 options:

1. Aber Ich kenne nicht über was muss ich schreiben!
2. Aber Ich kenne nicht dass über was ich schreiben muss!

Is any of these a good translation?

Comment: _was_ isn't used to connect sentences.

Comment: The dass should be spelled das.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: "Ich kenne nicht, was ich beschreiben soll!"? "Ich weiß nicht, was soll es bedeuten, dass ich so traurig bin."?

Comment: Your example is improper English. *was* can be a relative pronoun similar to a conjunction,  as in "Ich weiß nicht, was ich schreiben soll." - "I do not know what to write."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the following sentence:

> Ich weiß nicht, **worüber** ich schreiben muss!

**worüber** means *`about what`*

So your original sentence becomes:

*I don't know, `what` I have to write about!*

But this feels a little "forced", the better sounding formulation would be:

> Ich weiß nicht, **worüber** ich schreiben **soll**!

meaning:

*I don't know, what I should write about!*